# How to show CActiveForm::errorSummary() on ajax requests? (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

On **Post** requests `<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model) ?>` automatically appears on the page after submitting form and show summary of form errors. How can make it appear on **Ajax** requests?

### Edit:

Following is my view file:

```
<div class="form" >
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
        'id'=>'change-profile-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CProfile'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'validateOnChange'=>true,
            'validateOnType'=>false,
        ),
    ));
    ?>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                'update',
                Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CProfile'),
                array(
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'data'=>"js:$('#change-profile-form').serialize()",
                    'success'=>'callback',
                    'beforeSend'=>'before',
                ),
                array(
                    'id'=>'update-button'.uniqid(),
                    'class'=>'submit-button',
                )
            );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget() ?>

</div> <!-- End The Profile Form  -->
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,'Please solve these errors:') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

clientOptions can also accept:

```
'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError){ 
     if(hasError){
         // do something with: data
     }
 }'
```

What i do is something like this http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/4j3-6rx then on the server side, i just return a json message that gets parsed on the ajax success callback, pretty simple.

Comment: I don't understand your way. I just want show `#change-email-form_es_` when form has error(s). How do it?